# How to backup and read login logs files

Tags: logfiles

On Raspbian one can read the recent login history using the command 'last'.

Then if one copies the log files in /var/log/ to on a different Linux system and want to read the login, which methods are available? The file /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/lastlog seem binary files and cannot be read using less/vim.

Comment: You could try `last -f file_name` - it probably won't give the correct username (because most Linux commands use uid).

Comment: So the file /var/log/wtmp does not contain constant usernames, and when the file is read in different system, then the usernames are read differently from the original names?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know - but in general usernames exist in mapping to uid (e.g. `ls -lan` shows numeric uid - which is what is stored in file attributes, although `pi` is a directory name). On default Raspbian `pi` == `1000`

Comment: Okay, I found that usernames are read correctly from wtmp. But I have no idea how to read lastlog

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lastlog&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+5.0-RELEASE has info - yes, it's freebsd, but posix is posix ... `The lastlog file is a linear array of lastlog structures indexed by a user's UID` and `The utmp file is a linear array of utmp structures indexed by a terminal line number` - the structure for both is defined as well